# using jquery selectors containsCI with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

I need to search multiple values at the same time.

```
<div class="person">
    <div class="first_name">John</div>
    <div class="last_name">Johnson</div>
</div>

var search = "son";

var $found= $(".last_name:containsCI('" + search + "')").parent();
```

This works correctly as far as it goes, finding "son" in .last_name works correctly, but what I really want is to be able to search both fields at the same time so I can capture using both name fields.  i.e. I should also capture .person if I search for "John Smith".

Comment: What's `:containsCI()`? (I mean, I can guess, but given that it isn't a standard jQuery selector it wouldn't hurt to explain...)

Comment: you could add a common class for both the target fields and search using that classname as u have done aove

Comment: @nnnnnn: I assumed it's a case insensite contains

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `label` tags for showing that information this could do the trick

```
var $found= $("label:containsCI('" + search + "')").parent();
```

If you have a container element to narrow the search, you could do

```
var $found= $("#container_id label:containsCI('" + search + "')").parent();
```

Or simply

```
var $found= $("#container_id :containsCI('" + search + "')").parent();
```